# Filter out <p>&nbsp;</p> with php and mysql

Tags: php, filtering

I am trying to to filter out numerous (500000) <p>&nbsp ;</p> entries in my WordPress site, but I cannot figure out how. I've tried many thing, but still no luck.
Also many \n\n&nbsp ; entries should be filtered out and replaced by ''

Here is my code:

```
$query = mysql_query('select meta_id, meta_value from wp_postmeta where meta_value like "%<p>&nbsp;</p>%" ');
while ($item = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    echo "item with id:" . $item[meta_id]." found<br>";
    $string = preg_replace('~<p>&nbsp;<\/p>~i', '',  $item["meta_value"]);
    $id = $item[meta_id];
    $q = mysql_query('update wp_postmeta set meta_value = "$string" where meta_id = "$id"') or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: if you want to Convert all applicable characters to HTML entities  use  htmlentities($item["meta_value"]) or if you want to replace a string you can use  str_replace("<p>&nbsp;<\/p>", "", $item["meta_value"])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not trying the MySQL replace function?

```
update table_name set field_name = replace(field_name,'string_to_find','string_to_replace');
```